# Netcat localhost command not working on WSL 2.0 Ubuntu

Tags: networking, netcat

I'm using netcat to practise my network lessons' exercises. I need to access to my localhost port 7777 using the following command on the prompt:

```
nc localhost 7777
```

I'm using wsl 2.0 on Windows 11, idk if that is the problem because as far as I know, it worked properly after upgrading to W11.
When I put the command, the usual is that I can see what is happening on that port, but now it's like it closes immediately and doesn't allow me to hear on that port.
Do you know how to solve it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen from one end.
So you have to issue two commands :

```
nc -l localhost 7777
```

and in another terminal session

```
nc  localhost 7777
```